terminal: wandb CLI installation does not work?
This is a really basic issue, but for some reason I cannot install the wandb CLI with pip; whenever I try to wandb login I get a zsh: command not found: wandb error (I'm on a Mac).
What is confusing is that I'm able to run both
pip3 install wandb

and alternatively
python3 -m pip install wandb

without any issues - it just says the package is installed and moves on. I'm assuming that the python package installation works but for some reason the CLI doesn't?

pip3 show --files wandb | grep '^Location:\|/bin/' then add the directory to $PATH.

from W&B here. I think that you have a PATH issue, not related to W&B.

Are you installing on an environment (you probably should)? I recommend miniforge (conda) or poetry.
You probably have a conflicting pip from the system and the environment management. You can use which pip to sort this issue.
Sometimes, the terminal configs file ~/.zshrc overrides the PATH variable. Check your PATH variable manually and modify it accordingly.

